# Functions queue for async execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a set of functions which I need to execute in sync way (after one finishes I called another with result from previous function). Every function takes dictionary as parameter.
Is there any module already done for node.js or javascript ?

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q, https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES5 `Array.reduce`:

```
function queueFunctions(funcs, initialValue, commonData) {
    funcs.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue/*, index, array*/){
        return currentValue(previousValue, commonData);
    }, initialValue);
}
```

For example:

```
queueFunctions([prompt, confirm, alert], 'foo?');
```